# Using Magicline with Flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, flexslider, magicline

I'm using Flexslider for a slideshow and I'm trying to use [Magicline](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/) with it.

So far everything works good, however if I click on the arrows to go to the next slide the magicline doesn't move - it only works if I hover over an element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** I made a fiddle of it - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNxdU/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
    <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide-li small-slide-li slide-1 flex-active-slide">
                <div class="sml-slide-titles CAPS center">Retail</div>
                <div class="slide-icon"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="slide-li small-slide-li slide-2">
                <div class="sml-slide-titles CAPS center">Retail</div>
                <div class="slide-icon"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="slide-li small-slide-li slide-3">
                <div class="sml-slide-titles CAPS center">Retail</div>
                <div class="slide-icon"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="slide-li small-slide-li slide-4">
                <div class="sml-slide-titles CAPS center">Retail</div>
                <div class="slide-icon"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="flex-direction-nav">
    <li>
        <a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

jQuery(function scroller($) {

    var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
        $mainNav = $("#carousel");
    $mainNav.append("<div id='arrow'></div>");
    var $magicLine = $("#arrow");
    var $selector = $("#carousel li").position().left;
    console.log($selector)
    $magicLine
        .css("left", $("#carousel li.flex-active-slide").left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $("#carousel li").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
        });
    }, 

    function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $("#carousel li.flex-active-slide").position().left,
        });    
    });



});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, I see no place where you check the "click left arrow" and "click right arrow" events, so it's normal that the `#arrow` only moves on hover.

Add this bit of code at the end of your javascript (to handle the click events):

```
 $('#sml-slider-container').on('click', '.flex-next, .flex-prev', function() {
     $el = $('.flex-active-slide');
     leftPos = $el.position().left;
     $magicLine.stop().animate({
         left: leftPos,
     });
 });
```

And you're done.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zNxdU/6/

(*update*: I forgot the . in `.flex-prev` selector. Updated my answer and the fiddle)

Comment: This solution works, but using the flexslider's "after" function would give a more concise solution.

Comment: @Fresh yes but his method has an instant reaction - better suited for the user

Comment: @pinouchon was wondering how to do this on swipe on a mobile?

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/dtk63/

I've made use of flexsliders "[after](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)" event handler to make magicline move when you click the left/right arrow. "after" is ideal for this feature as it fires after each slider animation completes.

The code to do this is here:

```
after: function (slider) {
 $('.carousel-li.flex-active-slide').mouseover();
}
```

You'll be hard pressed to come up with a simpler solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

as you append the arrows they need the "on" function in jquery as they where not preloaded in the document. See https://api.jquery.com/on/

So the click event for the arrows need the on function attached, I think you can use something similar to your hover function.